# IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin problem

Tags: scala, plugins

I have a issue with new Intellij IDEA 10 and Scala plugin. The editor is permanently freezes when I'm typing anything in the Scala source files. In the other files (java and other) editor works good.

Structure view, scala inspection and show members features are switched off. Heap size increased to 1Gb(the IDE actually used just a half of it).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have same problems after updating to 10.5 version, it such annoying, thinking about rolling back to previous version

Answer (score 2):

There should be a series of thread dumps in the logs directory (~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea10 on MacOS X, ~/.IntelliJIdea10/system/log on Linux, %USERHOME%/.IntelliJIdea10/system/log on Windows). Please file a YouTrack issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/ and attach the thread dump files to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with IDEA 9. After lots of searching, I found a strange solution: Deactivate the toolbar and/or navigation bar. (Menu: View -> Toolbar, Navigation Bar)

This actually solved it for me. The explanation was that IDEA had a problem rebuilding the icons in those bars somehow and would sometimes get stuck. I don't know if the problem persists with IDEA 10, and I don't know if it will fix your problem. But maybe you want to give it a try. Deactivate those two bars, restart IDEA and see if those interruptions come again.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, in the IDEA 10 it doesn't work. In IDEA 9 there was not such problem. Well, actually in IDEA9 freezes happens too, but not so often.

Comment: Strange... I don't have those freezes. I'm using the community edition of IDEA 10 on a MacBoc with OS X. I have deactivated all plugins except for: Key promoter, PluginUpdateNotifier, Properties Support, Scala, TabReorder, TabSwitch, Subversion integration. Maybe you can narrow down the list of active plugins at least. When you have no plugin active that I don't have active too and still get the freezes, we know it can't be a plugin problem.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is just a Java application, so take advantage of the diagnostic tools for the JVM.

Capture a thread dump during one of the editor lock ups using `jstack`, as described [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5273948#5273948). You could also use `jconsole` or `jvisualvm`.

Comment: Debug your IDE using diagnostic tools because *it* crashes? That sounds fun.